Form value not passed to controller
I have a simple application; given a SpecificationName, it will load all attributes for that SpecificationName.
SamplesController:
public ActionResult Create()
{
     SampleVM samplevm = new SampleVM();

     return View();
}

My Javascript file:
$(function () {
    var Samples = [];

    $('#SpecificationName').change(function () {
        var specificationName = $(this).val();
        var lotId = $('#LotId').val();
        var url = 'https://localhost:44372/Samples/FilterAttributes';
        var queryString = url + '?specificationName=' + specificationName + '&lotId=' = lotId;


        $('#filter-table').load(queryString);
    });
});

It loads the attributes table correctly. But when I submit, nothing is passed to the controller; samples is null:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SaveSamples(List<SampleVM> samples)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          Sample sample = new Sample();

          db.Samples.Add(sample);

          return RedirectToAction("Create");
      }

      return View(samples);
}

I pass @model IEnumerable<IQC.ViewModels.SampleVM> to both Create.cshtml view and FilterAttributes.cshtml partial view.
What am I doing wrong?
POST payload:
__RequestVerificationToken: some token
item.SpecificationAttributeId: 37627
item.AttributeId: 994
item.Value: 1
item.SpecificationAttributeId: 37628
item.AttributeId: 993
item.Value: 1

The same of it is SaveSamples. Is this the reason why it is not being passed to samples in the controller? Is there a way to change the name?

When you inspect the POST payload using your browser's dev tools -> network tab, is it named samples and matches to type List<SampleVM> ?  It would be helpful if you edited your question and added what the POST payload looks like structurally.

The name in POST comes from the name attribute on the field in the form.  Or you could change the method in the controller so it accepts the name of the object that is being posted.  If you're unsure, you could edit your post and show us an example of the form fields so we can see it.

According to the illustrated payload, it seems that you submit a flatten structure. Thus, it can be only bound to a scalar model value:
[HttpPost]
//public ActionResult SaveSamples(List<SampleVM> samples) { ... }
public ActionResult SaveSamples(SampleVM sample) { ... }

Check this scenario to make sure that it is ok for the scalar model item. If this works, extend your current view part and render an index-ed based inputs names to submit a list-based payload instead of scalar/single, smth like:
How does MVC 4 List Model Binding work?
MVC Model Binding with Dynamic Collection
